# What is the difference between a project manager and a principal agent in construction

Tags: pmbok, responsibility

What is the difference Between a project manager and a principal agent in construction.

Is there a difference in the challenges experienced on construction projects (eg cost and time overruns) by a PA or a PM? Thus a comparison of how the two professions fare when it comes to running successful projects.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://www.projectmanagement.org.za/page/PrincipalAgency/The-role-of-the-Principal-Agent-across-the-Built-Environment-Professio.htm), the Principal Agent is the person appointed by the client and who has full authority and obligation to act in terms of the construction contracts.

A Project Manager is the person who ensures everything runs according to plan. A Project Manager may not have any or much authority when it comes to changing anything.

It would seem that it's the Project Manager's responsibility to keep the project on schedule, and the Principal Agent's responsibility to authorize any changes needed.